# 500 server error using IPython notebook on Windows

Tags: windows-7, python, node.js, ipython

I've just done a fresh install of IPython notebook on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

The steps I took were:

1. Install Python 3.4.1 from python.org
2. > pip install ipython[notebook]
3. > pip install pywin numpy pygments nodeenv

I can open a notebook fine. However, when I select `File > Print Preview` or `File > Download as HTML` I get a 500 server error.

The stack trace is:

```
2014-08-07 09:44:25.431 [NotebookApp] Loaded template full.tpl
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\IPython\nbconvert\filters\markdown.py:78: UserWarning: Node.js 0.9.12 or later wasn't found.
Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.
  "Nbconvert will try to use Pandoc instead.")
WARNING:tornado.general:500 GET /nbconvert/html/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb?download=false (::1): nbconvert failed: you need to have pywin32 installed for this to work
ERROR:tornado.access:{
  "Dnt": "1",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb",
  "Host": "localhost:8888",
  "Connection": "keep-alive",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6",
  "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
}
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET /nbconvert/html/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb?download=false (::1) 156.01ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Users/Tom%20Oakley/Documents/IPython%20test.ipynb
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 1.00ms referer=None
```

I thought that `nodeenv` was node.js

Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

1. Right-click on the `Command Prompt` in the Start Menu.
2. Select `Run as administrator`.
3. Select `Yes` in the User Account Control dialog.
4. Run `ipython notebook` in the resulting Command Prompt window.

Basically, it has to be run as administrator for some reason.